# Is is possible to have some 0-value pixels as NoData while others not in GeoTiff using GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal

I have a GeoTiff file in byte. It has values ranges from 0 to 101, while 0 is NoData value, and 1 - 101 are real data. I want to recode the actual data to 0 - 100, but also have the NoData pixels remain 0. This means that in the result Tiff file, there are some 0-value pixels are real data and the others are NoData. Is it possible to do this process with GDAL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to do *exactly* what you say in your question.  When looking at a given pixel, GDAL decides if it's `NoData` by looking at the numeric value.  A given pixel will either be `NoData` (if it's `0` in your case) or not.  Zero can't be *both* a "real" value and  a `NoData` value.

But there are other possibilities, depending on how you want to eventually use the resulting raster.

You could add an additional "mask" band to your raster (with the [`nearblack`](http://www.gdal.org/nearblack.html) utility and its `setmask` option, for example).  For each pixel, the new mask band would have a value of `0` when it's a `NoData` value, and a value of `255` for everything else.  Depending on how you're using the data, the value of the mask band at a given pixel would allow you to tell the difference between the `NoData` zeros and the "real" zeros.

Answer (score 5):

No it is not.  The NoDataValue is purely a metadata flag that signals to the interpreter (human, GIS, whatever) that raster pixels with this NoDataValue should be **interpreted** as NoData.

The internal data structure for tiffs requires that every pixel have a value associated with it. It is not possible to flag certain sets of a value as NoData and certain sets of the same value as "real".

Comment: Could the OP change the NoData value (and update the tiff) to something like 255 and then recode as described?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a second band indicating real or NoData. Create your NoData band. [Answer from csd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/229675/92255) suggests how to.

Create multi band raster with `-separate` tag in [gdal_merge.py](http://gdal.org/gdal_merge.html):

```
gdal_merge.py -separate -o out.tif data.tif nodata.tif
```